# What is more pythonic: Using getattr or inline if statement to retrieve a default value

Tags: python

My question is,

Which of the following is more pythonic:

`getattr(object, field, None)` vs `object.field if object else None`

I lean towards the if statement because the getattr seems to assume that an object actually does exist and we are checking if the field exists.  Which is not what we are trying to accomplish.

Also when benchmarking: The if statement is consistently 4x faster.

EDIT:

If it isn't already obvious, this is pseudo code.

Comment: Those are not equivalent statements. The first returns the field attribute of object. If the field attribute does not exist, then it returns None. The second returns the field attribute of object if object is truthy. Otherwise it returns None.

Comment: "the getattr seems to assume that an object actually does exist and we are checking if the field exists. Which is not what we are trying to accomplish" - then what *are* you trying to accomplish? The `getattr` code makes perfect sense for the use case it's intended for.

Comment: They are equivalent in their returned values.  They will either return the value that exists at field on the object, or they will return None.  Assuming the object has standard getattr methods.

Comment: Also I assume that this is not real code, but please don't use keywords for variable names (i.e. don't use 'object' as a variable name). In this case object will always evaluate as True in the ternary statement.

Comment: @zkazanski: That is not really correct.  The first one will either return the value that exists, or return None.  The second will either return the object that value that exists, return None, or raise AttributeError.

Comment: The `if` statement assumes that `type(object)` hasn't overriden the method used to determine if `object` is truthy or not as well.

Comment: @BrenBarn Good point.

Comment: @chepner Also good point.

Comment: @Alex I see your point now.  I assumed that the object is a user written class and is inherently truthy. So ultimately there is no answer, without knowing more about the object in question.

Comment: @zkazanski Even if the object is always truthy, the two statements are not necessarily equivalent. See the second case in my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I had to type this up in an answer because it exceeded comment character limits. As I mentioned in the comments, those two statements are not equivalent.

Setup

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        setattr(self, attr_name, 'hi')

a1 = A('my_attr')
a2 = A('other_attr')
```

Here are the cases for the `getattr` statement.

```
getattr(a1, 'my_attr', None)  # evaluates to 'hi'

getattr(a2, 'my_attr', None)  # evaluates to None

getattr(a3, 'my_attr', None)  # raises NameError
```

Here are the cases for the ternary statement.

```
a1.my_attr if a1 else None  # evaluates to 'hi'

a2.my_attr if a2 else None  # raises AttributeError

a3.my_attr if a3 else None  # raises NameError
```

The second case is different under the two regimes.

Furthermore if instances of `A` evaluate as `False` the two regimes can differ in a different way.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        setattr(self, attr_name, 'hi')
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

a1 = A('my_attr')
a2 = A('other_attr')
```

The `getattr` statements evaluate the same, but the ternary statements now evaluate as follows:

```
a1.my_attr if a1 else None  # evaluates to None

a2.my_attr if a2 else None  # evaluates to None

a3.my_attr if a3 else None  # raises NameError
```

Now the first case is different under the two regimes.